# shell script : enter argument, prompt and response

Tags: shell

Need shell script which display as below:

Some thing : when execute ./abc.sh

display :

Enter 1 for link

Enter 2 for check

If user enter 1 then `date` command should run
if user enter 2 then `java -version` command should run.

I know it's pretty easy but I am new in shell.

Comment: i don't think you should use the java related tags.

Comment: You are not new to Stack Overflow, though. You should know better than to ask for code without providing at least some effort at solving the problem yourself first.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that with [`read`](http://ss64.com/bash/read.html) and something like,

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Display options
echo "Enter 1 for link"
echo "Enter 2 for check"
# read user input into NUM
read NUM
if [ "$NUM" == "1" ]; then
  date
else
  java -version
fi
```